# SelectIndexChanged Event fired in asp.net when changing index in jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I had one dropdown and OnSelectedIndexChanged event related to that dropdown in asp.net. Now my problem is when I am changing index of dropdown using jQuery, OnSelectedIndexChanged event also fired in asp.net. Please tell me how to solve this.

P.S.: I had used update panel in page and used trigger also but then also no luck.

Comment: Please show some code, or make a JSFiddle.

Comment: `protected void ddlBranchCode_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Branch Changed Code
    }`      and then I have changed some different ddl with jQuery function associated with it. In jQuery function I am making selectedindex=1 of ddlBranch and at that time .net function is being called automatically.

Comment: Please add the code to your question, properly formatted.

Comment: do you want to carry both event?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just change the value?

```
$('#yourDrop').val('Value');
```

If I'm not wrong, you need to use the $('#yourDrop').change() to make the onchange event fire in this case. If you don't want this event to fire, I think that just changing the value will work. Let'me know if it works for you.

Comment: jQuery function is working perfectly. Only problem is when it changes the value of _ddlBranch_ then _OnSelectedIndex_ in asp.net is also getting fired.

Comment: You can try a "return false" after you change the value.